# Rails: update user but password is invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a payment api that takes bank account info and user info. I catch the api response and use ajax to send the infomation into my controller where I try to save the information to my user. When I save I get the error `Validation failed: Password can't be blank, Password is invalid:` Any ideas?

Bank Controller:

```
def addbank
  @user = current_user
  @user.phone_number = params[:phone_number]
  @user.birth_year = params[:year]
  @user.bank_uri = (params['bank_acct_uri'])
  @user.save! # <------- ERROR here!
  # Code was removed to be more clear
end
```

User Controller:

```
def update
  # update user controller has been commented out but the error is still there
end
```

User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :email,:password,:password_confirmation,:phone_number,:birth_year

      attr_accessor :password
      before_save :encrypt_password
      before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }

      VALID_PASSWORD_REGEX = # some reg-expression
      VALID_PHONE = # some reg-expression
      validates_confirmation_of :password
      validates :password, presence: true, format:{  with: VALID_PASSWORD_REGEX }
      validates :phone_number, format: { with: VALID_PHONE }, if: :phone_number
end
```

### Edit: Why is saving user not hitting my update user controller?

Comment: Are you using Devise?

Comment: no i am not using devise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid the validation of one particular field (password in your case), but you want to do all the other validations (for example phone number), you can do something like this:

```
attr_accessor :skip_password

validates :password, presence: true, format:{  with: VALID_PASSWORD_REGEX }, unless: :skip_password
```

Then, in your controller, you could do:

```
def addbank
  @user = current_user
  @user.skip_password = true # We don't want to validate this..
  @user.phone_number = params[:phone_number]
  @user.birth_year = params[:year]
  @user.bank_uri = (params['bank_acct_uri'])
  @user.save! # <------- ERROR here!
  # Code was removed to be more clear
end
```

Do this at your own risk ~~

Comment: This sounds great and I will probably use it but how could this backfire.

Comment: I am not sure if you want to have users without a password? It really depends on your needs.

Comment: I would have to add a skip_password column to users but after I set it to true how would I then set it to false lol

Comment: You don't need to add a column. This is just to bypass the validation. Later on you could set the password and password confirmation column.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to save without validation:

```
@user.save(:validate => false)
```

UPDATE:

```
if !@user.valid? && @user.errors[:phone_number].any?
  #do not save
else
 @user.save(:validate => false)
end
```

Comment: I thought of doing that but what if the phone number is invalid

Comment: I am updated my answer, but @Nobita suggested best solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

Where are you storing the encrypted password?

If you store it in `password` then it will fail validation every save because it doesn't equal `password_confirmation`.

I'd recommend putting the password in a separate field.

```
#from the User Model
attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation

validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
validates_confirmation_of :password

def password=(password)
    @password = password
    self.password_digest = BCrypt::Password.create(@password, :cost => 14)
end

def authenticate(password)
    BCrypt::Password.new(self.password_digest) == password
end
```

This way the password gets hashed and saved to password_digest and won't trigger a validation error on save.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post this as I am about 95% certain this is the cause, but I apologize if I'm off.

I believe the cause of this is because the user's password is indeed blank. If you look at your database, you'll see a column probably called `encrypted_password`, which is never directly accessed via your model, nor is it ever de-crypted into your accessible `password` and `password_confirmation` attributes.

In order to update the user, you will have to enter re-enter the password, or use the `save(false)` method to (potentially dangerously) bypass validations.